# Editable interactable grid - Display modified value after saving without primary key

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, interactive-grid

I'm working with APEX 23.1 and have difficulties when trying to refresh an IG with complicated source SQL. The example is as following:

I have two tables `VALUES` and `NAMES` in database. There might be some names that does not appear in the table `VALUES`. What I want is displaying those missing names as well in the IG (so that users don't have to create new row and choose name, but rather they only need to input to value if want to add that name into table `VALUES`). Its purpose is to reduce number of clicks requires for adding new information.

In IG, only records of one `obj_id` is displayed at a time and column `name` is set to primary key:

- If user updates the existing rows (rows with prior values) -> Update statement in processes DML
- If user updates the new rows (rows with no prior value) -> Insert statement in processes DML
- If user deletes values of the existing rows (rows with prior values) -> Delete statement in processes DML

My current situation is that I can display IG as expected and successfully update data in `VALUES`. However, by clicking SAVE in IG, the modified values disappear. They can only be displayed when I reload page. (from what I know, it might be due to the column used for primary key in IG. But I cannot use any other column as primary key since those temporarily added rows in yellow don't have `ROWID` in table `VALUES`)

[image]

Is there any way to fix this problem of refresh or any other approach that procudes desired outcomes?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I had a similar issue long time back. Only solution was to do a page refresh - the model needs to be rebuilt since the underlying query results have changed as a result of the update. Because the PK is missing for those rows, the changes cannot be shown on the client side

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I made column name as PK and only alow user to update current row, so PK shouldn't be empty. However, I found the reason for the behavior. It's because I did not submit a page item needed in source sql query of IG

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the reason for that. I need to submit a page item used for source sql of IG.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).